# The computer's hostname is not set correctly

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, centos, active-directory

So I wanted to connect my centos VM to my Windows Server VM that is currently hosting my Active Directory Server (both are on Host-Only Network). I know that the server is working, up and running, and is accepting connections because in the past I've been able to connect my Windows Machine with the AD Domain, and because `realm discover 192.168.0.5` returns

```
cherry.com
type: kerberos
realm-name: SPICE.COM
domain-name: spice.com
configured: no
server-software: active-directory
client-software: sssd
oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir sssd adcli samba-common-tools
```

(Along with a bunch required packages that I can confirm that I have downloaded).
My `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like `search spice.com\nnameserver 192.168.0.5`.

Furthermore, in my AD Server, under `Active Users and Computers` I've created a new user `canary`.
However, when I try to run `realm join --user=canary 192.168.0.5`, I get the `The computer's hostname is not set correctly` error. How would I be able to fix this and connect my centos machine to my AD Domain?
I'm willing to provide whatever information might be necessary.

Comment: If joining a domain, shouldn't you be specifying the...*domain*, not the IP address?

Comment: I tried both, both gave me the exact same results

Comment: Does the VM's hostname happen to be `canary`? (Within ADU&C, did you create a 'User' account or a 'Computer' account?)

Comment: The VM's hostname is not canary, however, within the ADU&C, I do have a User named `canary` yes